# How I get twidge to work with identi.ca?

Tags: command-line

I want to use twidge to connect to my identi.ca-Account. I already successfully authenticated the client against identi.ca. But if I execute `twidge lsrecent` I get the following error:

```
twidge: user error (Bad response: 401)
```

What is wrong and has to be changed?

Answer (score 1):

This is a known bug and it is fixed in twidge_1.0.6.

You can download and install the latest build from https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/twidge_1.0.6_i386.deb

Read the bug report [here](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=601427)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't work. This bug-report is also written for Twitter, not identi.ca. I don't think identi.ca cancels an application, because it is open-source.

Comment: @Mnementh: The Identica platform doesn’t implement all the features of Twitter. You can see the status of their API. Major things to note are that Identi.ca doesn’t support direct messages, nor will it support —unseen options to various commands. Some of these options may be silently ignored, and others will return mysterious errors.

Updating works fine.

taken from twidge wiki: https://github.com/jgoerzen/twidge/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions

Comment: Even twidge lsrecent doesn't work. I used twidge earlier, it was included in Ubuntu before Lucid. At that time they didn't used the API, I needed to input my username and password, to give Twidge access to Identica. But at that time all functions worked fine, also direct messaging. Possibly I should look, if I can get the old version.